# Xdebug не подключается к IDE PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Есть vps с php70 и xdebug 2.5.0rc.
Конфиг Xdebug:

```
xdebug.xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=0


xdebug.remote_log = "/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

При включении валидации в phpstorm всё прекрасно находится.

[image: валидация сервера]

Но при попытке дебажить не видит точки остановок и не останавливается нигде.
Лог:

```
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 94.181.237.21:9000.
W: Creating socket for '94.181.237.21:9000', poll: Operation now in progress.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

Comment: на телефонную трубку в phpstorm нажимаете перед дебагом, чтоб захватить контекст, так скажем? Для дебага в phpstorm что нажимаете? маппинг настроили? он бывает нужен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский трубку нажимаю, phpstorm вообще не реагирует на соединение даже не вылетает окно с прозьбой настроить разметку.
Также находит и удаленный интерпретатор и показывает что есть xdebug

Comment: Какая версия PHPStorm?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в целом у вас работает отладка через xdebug в phpstorm (например, для локальных проектов), проблема только в данном случае с удаленным сервером? Пробовали с сервера подключаться к phpstorm, например, через telnet на 9000 порт?

Comment: @cronfy 2016.2, дебаг работает только если в роутере (tp-link)  добавлять виртуальный сервер и тогда дебаг может достать до меня, но такой вариант не идеален т.к. в моей сети не я 1 занимаюсь разработкой.
Telnet пробовал конечно он тоже не может достучаться.

Comment: Ага, тогда понятно. Вам нужен ssh port forwarding между вашим компьютером и vds https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/57289096

Comment: Если и после проброса порта не заработает, проверьте маппинг

Comment: @cronfy команда будет вот такая `ssh -R 9000:5.167.164.169:9000 admin@95.215.111.77` ?

Comment: @cronfy с тунелем заработало! спасибо!
Хотя помню как то на другом сервере работало без тунеля..
А какая опция для сервера будет менее нагрузочной
remote_autostart или remote_connectback или лучше вообще их выключить?

Comment: Лучше autostart убрать, а включать при необходимости: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session

Comment: @cronfy обязательно попробую, а есть ли возможность как то избавиться от необходимости создавать тунель каждый раз?

Comment: Запускать его при старте системы? Посмотрите в сторону autossh

Comment: @cronfy а на vps что то реально поменять что бы она могла находить мой пк ? т.к. при работе с некоторыми серверами xdebug отрабатывал хорошо

Comment: Может, те другие серверы были в вашей локальной сети? Если вы за NAT'ом, а сервер снаружи, то без туннеля или настройки роутера не обойтись.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49009/discussion-between-alex-kuvaev-and-cronfy).